# Dialect of the `[1.]` suffix in `\begin{enumerate}[1.]`?

Tags: enumerate, syntax

I have a tool (pandoc) that is producing tex.  Among the output is the following:

```
\begin{enumerate}[1.]
\item foo
\item bar
\item baz
\end{enumerate}
```

`pdflatex` then refuses to compile it with error "there is something wrong"

When I remove the `[1.]` it compiles successfully.

Is the use of this `[1.]` parameter some kind of dialect mismatch?

Which dialects if any support the construct and which do not?

Comment: You have to load the `enumerate` package.

Comment: alternatively you can load the `enumitem` package and use `[label=\arabic*.]` instead of `[1.]`

Comment: @ArTourter or use `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}` then in understands `[1.]`.

Comment: @daleif I had forgotten about that option! nice one.

Comment: Also works with `memoir` (as @daleif surely knows).

Comment: Of course, though, I still recommend enumitem, even with memoir

Answer (score 1):

You have to coerce Pandoc into adding

```
\usepackage{enumerate}
```

or

```
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
```

in the document preamble.